# Device administrator will not activate on Android TV box

Tags: android, android-tv, device-manager

I'm trying to enable the Device Administrator on my Android TV box.  I go to Settings/Security/Device Administrators and the Android Device Manager is there, but it is not selected.  If I check the box to activate it, it asks me to activate it, but after doing so, the box remains unchecked and the Android Device Manager is not activated.   Any ideas/settings/apk updates that might help?

Comment: I seem to recall other questions on this point, suggesting perhaps that Android TV simply does not support device administration.

Comment: It is supported and works, because I have it on another box and it works perfectly.  I'm just wondering if this specific ROM has it disabled somewhere.

Comment: We don't know what that specific ROM is, though.

Comment: Won't matter what ROM it is, because I won't be able to modify it, so I'm hoping there's another way to activate the device administrator or someone has a solution to this issue

Comment: You may want to try the given workarounds in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/OlBSEM5uDuc). Try wiping the cache partition or try to pause the twilight app (or a similar app) which acts as a screen overlay when activating device administrator. Hope that works for you too.

Comment: Already tried all of that @Teyam     None of it works.  Even tried reinstalling the Device Manager APK from the Play Store to hopefully override any of the default settings... nothing is working so far.  Thanks for responding!